# How to solve this simultaneous equation?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\cos x = \frac{y}{20}$$

$$\cos x =  \frac{y}{18}$$

How to solve the simultaneous equation above?
Is it possible?
The actual question is
http://postimg.org/image/6ip2356sx/

Comment: y/20 = y/18 so y=0

Comment: $y=0$ and $x=(2k+1)\pi/2$.

Comment: My vote for closing because you didn't care to explain the connection with the "actual question".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question based on the picture you've linked. Here's how you can get started. For one, all the tangent lines to the circle have normal lines that cross through the centre of the inscribed circle. Moreover, and perhaps not so obvious if you don't already know this, the angle bisector at each corner of the triangle also crosses the centre of the inscribed circle! The image looks something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFsLc.gif.

You can solve for, in your case, angles $P$, $Q$, and $R$ by making use of the cosine law. After cutting up your shape into all 6 smaller triangles, you can use of the sine law to find the "red" lengths, and then finally proceed to use $sin/cos/tan$ ratios to solve for what is asked. Hopefully this nudges you in the right direction, I'll leave the actual computation to you.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can't have $\cos x = \frac{y}{20} = \frac{y}{18}$ except for when $y=0$

when $y \neq 0$ then it's not possible. It becomes quantum bit. Two states at the same time :D

Comment: The actual question is this http://postimg.org/image/6ip2356sx/